# How to test threads

Tags: ruby, rspec, thread-synchronization

We have threads:

```
module Task
  def self.execute
    "result"
  end
end

threads = []
threads << Thread.new { Task.execute }
```

We need to specify the test that checks the result:

```
expect(Task.execute).to eq("result")
```

We added a thread inside a thread:

```
threads << Thread.new do
  deep_thread = Thread.new { Task.execute }
  deep_thread.join
end
```

How can we check the result of method calls inside a thread? How can we check that the two threads finished, and also check the result of `deep_thread`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the results of method calls separately outside of the thread logic.

Then test the thread creation logic separately with something like:

```
let(:thread) { double }
it 'creates threads' do
  expect(Thread).to receive(:new).exactly(5).times.and_return(thread)
  expect(thread).to receive(:join).exactly(5).times.and_return(true)
  expect(Task).to receive(:execute).exactly(5).times.and_return("xyz")
  expect(subject.execute).to eq "xyz"
end
```